# why p++ is much faster than p = p->next

Tags: c++, optimization

I allocated a large buffer for a link list structure, so nodes are in consecutive memory blocks.
when I try to iterate the link list, two ways lead to different performance as below:

```
while(index<ListCount) {
    if (first[index++].key == key) { return;}

}
```

another way is:

```
while(first) {
  if (first->key == key) { return; }
  first = first->next;
}
```

there is a big different in performance, the second way is far behind the first way, why this happened?

Each node contains 16 bytes variables, including the next pointer.

Comment: Not enough context.  Are you optimizing?  What structure is it that you're indexing?  Etc.

Comment: modified the problem, this is the real loop I use

Comment: Why does your code keep changing every few seconds? What version did you actually test for performance? I'm pretty sure your performance results are made up. The code you tested is not the code you posted. The first version is supposed to be a bit faster, but it should not make a big difference.

Comment: sorry for my changing. This is the final! The major difference is the way of iterate the link list, why this make different performance? in release mode and iterate 100000 times, the first one is 40% faster.

Comment: It does not make a big difference in performance. If you see a big difference, it means that you are still not telling us something important.

Comment: Most likely you are not measuring performance properly.  For example, how are you clearing cache between measurements?

Comment: Well that's not surprising, even if the nodes are sequential the CPU wouldn't know that, it can prefetch but even then the loop is limited by cache hit latency which is a lot higher than increment latency. That alone would suggest a perf difference of a factor of 4, but there are additional effects.

Comment: What type is `first`? We have no idea what its `operator[]` does, so I'm not sure how we could compare the two bits of code.

Comment: Well yes, if your data is arranged like an array and allows indexed access, by all means access through an index. Incrementing a register is among the fastest things you can do on a computer. For example, it's probably faster than doing nothing at all (NOP). `first = first->next` by contrast accesses a memory location a  register is pointing to (it dereferences a pointer), and loads the value there in the register. Yes, that can be much slower. It's kind of ... unsurprising.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be happy with pseudo code, so I'm answering with pseudo code.

I find it likely that the structure that you're indexing is a "linked" list.  Let's say that you have 1,000 elements in the linked list.  When you say,

```
yourList[1000]
```

The only way to get access to the 1000th element is to do this

```
counter = 1000;
while(counter-- > 0) { //Ignoring potential off by 1 errors, this is for demonstration purposes only
    node = node->next;
}
```

So, if in your loop, your goal is to reference each element once, by accessing an element by index you are visiting

Element 1: 1000 times
Element 2: 999 times
Element 3: 998 times
Element 4: 997 times
Etc, etc.

Because, a linked list does not have direct access to its elements, every time you access an element by index, it must crawl through each pointer to get to that element.

Comment: The question's first loop seems to preform random access on `first`. OP also implied that `first` was incrementable. It's unlikely the container is a list.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP intends, there's not enough detail, this was my best guess given the info there.

Comment: Supposing OP is using a list, what do you suppose `first` is and how does `first[index]` work?

Comment: because I allocated the link list in an array, void* buffer = new char[nodecount * sizeof(Node)], and then Node* first = buffer, so I can iterate the link list using an index.

Comment: I find speculating based on his code to be a waste of time and ignored it, because nobody has ANY clue what "first" is.  Therefore I'm going by his symptoms, and not by his code.

Comment: Just because the elements in your list happen to be aligned sequentially, doesn't mean that the structure can take advantage of that...